# CSS background picture not showing

Tags: html, css

I have the code bellow in the html file and the problem is the background picture is not showing, nor when I try doing it from the css file. Can somebody help me out what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
<head>
  <style>
  body{
    background-image: url("trees.jpg");
  }
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Post full code that you've tried.

Comment: do you have any content in your html page body ?

Comment: With a first look I can't say there is something wrong.
Check your url destination, likely your url have not been found.

Comment: works fine and can't reproduce this!

Comment: @AbdelazizMokhnache Yes!

Comment: You set the background for the <body> element but there is no <body> element in your html structure as of now.

Comment: show me your entire code if you want.

Comment: Try removing the quotes like so: `background-image: url(trees.jpg);`

Answer (score 0):

try using !important

```
<head>
  <style>
  body{
    background-image: url("trees.jpg") !important;
  }
  </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set height of your body if their is no-content in the body then the image will not show

secondly, this code will only work if your html file and image are both in same folder

```
<head>
  <style>
  body{
    background-image: url("trees.jpg");
  }
  </style>
</head>
```

if the image is in say `img` folder then you need to do this

```
body{
    background-image: url("img/trees.jpg");
}
```

but if the `img` folder is not in the same directory as html but is in it's parent directory. you need to do this

```
body{
    background-image: url("../img/trees.jpg");
}
```

Comment: the image is in the same directory

Comment: Gabriela, can you post your full code on codepen or upload it on zipyshare

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it can't find the file destination, try to check if you typed the file name right, even the file extension. Sometimes is the file extension in uppercase, like ".JPG".